# Starting a process via Javascript [Using Rhino JS]

Tags: javascript, process, rhino

I'm working with a tool that only allows for Javascript as the scriptting language. With the script, I need to launch a process. How would I go about this?

The javascript code is running on the client that will launch the process. The javascript interpeter is [RhinoJS](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

So my question remains: 
1. Is there a way that I can call a specific Java class from Rhino [ProcessBuilder]?
or 
2. Is there a way to launch an executable from Javascript? [I've tried the UniversalXPConnect route, but it turns out that the version of Rhino I'm using doesn't really worry about permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was quick [I found the answer right after I asked]:

```
var pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe", "c:\test");
pb.start();
```

Basically RhinoJS has a quirk to allow it to directly access Java functionality. So basically once should just launch the process from there.